# ES6 arrow function binding and gulp compiling error

Tags: reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6

I've been trying hard to accomplish code segment below, by reading official ES6 docs and other blogs:

```
onHomeStoreChange = () => (newState) {
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

I used this [link](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html). 
but it seems like gulp doesn't do its job correctly, I get `A semicolon is required after a class property` error but even after putting one `this` is still `undefined`. Here is part of gulp file that uses transform.

```
appBundler
    // transform ES6 and JSX to ES5 with babelify
    .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]})
        //.transform(babelify.configure({stage: 0}))
    .bundle()
    .on('error',gutil.log)
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDestination));
```

I use react `0.14.5` and these are my dev dependencies.

```
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
"babelify": "7.2.0",
"browserify": "^12.0.1",
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-streamify": "^1.0.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
"vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
```

I'm confused and any help would be much appreciated.

**edit - adding react complete code**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { //put componentWillMount code in constructor
    super(props);

    //this.bindMethods();
    this.state = HomeStore.getState();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    HomeStore.listen(this.onHomeStoreChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    HomeStore.unListen(this.onHomeStoreChange);
  }

  onHomeStoreChange = (newState) => {
    //I had syntax error here
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          components will go here
        </div>
      );
  }

  bindMethods() {
    this.onHomeStoreChange = this.onHomeStoreChange.bind(this);
  }
}
```

If I use bindMethods() it's working but not =>

Comment: Can you show the actual code surrounding this segment also?

Comment: use it like this: `onHomeStoreChange = (newState)  => this.setState(newState);`

Comment: @thefourtheye updated

Comment: Why are you even using arrow function there?

Comment: good question, because onHomeStoreChange(newState) {this.setState(newState);} throws undefined error if I don't use bindMethods(). that's just not cool when you have too many components.

Comment: Class properties are ES7! Since there's no standard yet this is an experimental feature. The proposed spec demands a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra set of brackets. An arrow function should take its argument in the first set of brackets:

```
onHomeStoreChange = (newState) => {
    this.setState(newState);
};
```

The error you're seeing is because you have effectively defined `onHomeStoreChange` as `() => (newState)`, and then followed it with and extra `{...}` block.

Comment: Hi N3dst4. You hare partially correct, I had syntax error, take a look at this link http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus/#arrow-functions  but now it's bitching about semicolon, one I put it it's OK. But there are tutorials that dont have semicolon.

Comment: It's lame to put semicolon if the function is non-native react component method.

Comment: Yeah, you probably don't need the semicolon. You do need to fix the arrow function syntax though ;)

Comment: Fixed it. Any idea why gulp throws semicolon error now?

Comment: There's an open Babel issue about removing that restriction https://github.com/feross/standard/issues/372. Seems it was briefly part of the standard (to require semicoons on class properties) and got added to babel.